# Does the wave function decay?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, entropy, quantum-measurements

Does the wave function decay? Is the wave function subject to entropy? Does a particle decay while it's in superposition or does decay start when a measurement occurs?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you asking about what happens to the wave function of an unstable particle that is undergoing a decay process, and how that works - e.g. a muon?

Comment: Could you be more thorough in explaining what you are really asking? To me, it's a lot of terms without any context and coherence.

Comment: You may want to read this:https://phys.org/news/2020-02-scientists-quantum.html

Comment: @Yuan Fang : A wonderful illustration of decoherence showing the withering away of terms in the density matrix; but not sure if that is what this OP is asking for or if they're asking about unstable particles, hence why a lot asking clarifying questions...

Comment: @YuanFang - How do we know the same process is not also happening when not filmed?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer - As a layman I would be asking the same question - sort of like "does the wavefunction continue eternally" - just my guess

Comment: Actually there is work on this by Raczka in the 70s using non-unitary representation: see Raczka, R. "A theory of relativistic unstable particles." Annales de l'IHP Physique théorique. Vol. 19. No. 4. 1973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decay of an initial density of particles governed by stochastic differential equation (SDE) dynamics to the invariant equilibrium density is a classic topic in statistical mechanics, for which you may see the book by [Risken](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540615309). Given a stochastic process $x_s \sim p(s,x)$, for all $0 \leq s$, with the SDE dynamics $d x_s = b(x_s) ds + \sigma dw_s$ and the corresponding linear Fokker-Planck (FP) partial differential equation (PDE) dynamics $\partial_t p = \mathcal{L}^\dagger p$, the question posed is: will any initial density *decay* to the invariant density $p^\infty(x)$ which solves the stationary FP equation *and* at what rate? Such analyses have been explored for certain systems, namely, [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck and Langevin systems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781493913220). The key idea is to consider the initial density as a perturbation from the equilibrium given as $p(0,x) = p^\infty(x) + p^\infty(x) \tilde{p}(0,x)$ and prove that $\tilde{p}(s,x)$ vanishes under the limit $s \rightarrow +\infty$, by using the eigen properties of the generator $\mathcal{L}^\dagger$ of the SDE which is indeed the adjoint of the forward FP operator $\mathcal{L}$. Therefore, properties of the SDE dynamics determine whether or not we can show that the equilibrium density is indeed attained by particles with any arbitrary initial density. This property is, in fact, the *reversibility* of the dynamics of the stochastic process.

Analogously for the linear Schrödinger equation, eigen properties and corresponding stability results have been analyzed, in particular see the comprehensive book by [Berezen](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780792312185) on this topic, with extensive exploration for various classes of Schrödinger potentials. Recently, these ideas have found applications in the theory of mean field games (MFGs) starting with the seminal work in the linear or [integrator dynamics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782409000531) regime (similar to the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck case in the physics literature) and more recently in the case of [Langevin dynamics](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8632750). The latter work uses the imaginary-time linear Schrödinger equation formulation of the original problem, thus relying on eigen properties of the Schrödinger operator.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I don't know what I need to clarify, you answered the question perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @GeneticAvatar. I hope that helped and can let you know that this topic has recently attracted attention due to the applicability in the case of mean field games, which is a relatively new theory.